# How to specify correctly a file

Tags: import, spss, hmisc

i'm trying to import a spss- dataset in R.

I already tried read.spss and spss.get, both gave me the same error:

meinspss <- read.spss(C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Caspar\Desktop\Studium\Master\SoSe 14\Aktuelle FF der emp. Finanzwissenschaft und Wirtschaftspolitik (SteinerFossen)\Daten\pkal.sav")
**Error: unexpected input in "meinspss <- read.spss(C:\"**

I also tried "/" and "\" but got every time the same error.

As beginner in R I suppose that there is a problem with my specification of file-path.

I'm thankfull for every hint.

Caspar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name should be quoted. You are missing the starting quote:

```
meinspss <- read.spss("C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/Caspar/Desktop/Studium/Master/SoSe 14/Aktuelle FF der emp. Finanzwissenschaft und Wirtschaftspolitik (SteinerFossen)/Daten/pkal.sav")
```